# Is there any other way to convert string value into integer value in jsp? I am trying a basic program in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>AddModule | Home page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
   <form action="op.jsp">
   <div class="card">
   <div class="card-header bg-dark text-white">
   <h3>Provide me a number</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="card-body">
   <div class="form-group">
   <input name="n1" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter n1">
   </div>
   <div class=form-group>
   <input name="n2" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter n2">
   </div>
   </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Divide</button>
   </div>
   
   </div>
   </div>
   </form>
   </div>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

> **Getting an exception in op.jsp named java.lang.NumberFormatException**

*HTTP Status 500-Internal Server Error*

**op.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Jsp Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
String n1= request.getParameter("n1");
String n2= request.getParameter("n2");
int a=Integer.parseInt(n1);
int b=Integer.parseInt(n2);
int c=a/b;
%>
<h3>Result is <%=c %></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

**While converting value from string to integer it is generating an exception**

*Also Tried below code but still not working*

> 

```
<%int n1=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("n1"));
int n2=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("n1"));
int c=n1/n2 %>
```

Comment: Do you enter any numbers in the text fields before you press "Divide"?

Comment: No, showing before entering

Comment: Please go to `index.html` and not `op.jsp` directly

Comment: Thanks it works.But can you explain why going first to html page and then jsp page?

Comment: Your `index.html` page lets you input numbers and send them to `op.jsp`. If you go to `op.jsp` directly, then there are no numbers to work with. If you want to go to `op.jsp` directly then you must manually give it numbers by writing `op.jsp?n1=42&n2=7` in the URL bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with your code, but rather how you run it.

You need to access `index.html` first to allow you to input numbers, then hit `Divide`. This will invoke `op.jsp` with `n1` and `n2` as parameters.

If you try to access `op.jsp` directly, your code will run without values for `n1` and `n2`. If you don't have input, then trying to parse input as integers will obviously fail.

If you want to simplify testing, you can manually specify HTTP GET query parameters in the URL using `op.jsp?n1=42&n2=7`

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
String n1 = request.getParameter("n1");
String n2 = request.getParameter("n2");
int n1Val,n2Val;
if(n1 != null){
n1Val=Integer.parseInt(n1);
}
if(n2!=null){
n2Val=Integer.parseInt(n2);
}int c;
if(n1 != null && n2!=null)c=n1Val + n2val;
%>
```